# Give permissions to members of my group to post on it | Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

sorry for the Google translator, I've been looking for almost everything online, and since the rules of Graph Api have been changed, I've had many problems.

I have a group on facebook that has the privacy "closed", but I want to give access to all my members so that they can publish on it using Graph Api, if I am admin if I can publish, but if I am a member, the error from:

> *(# 200) The user has not authorized the application to perform this action.*

How can I give them permission to publish in my group?

Comment: Only by making them group admins, too ... which would likely be a rather bad idea. Other than that, you can at most use your own access token, so that the post will appear as made by your user, and then maybe add a "Written by: Foo bar" at the top of the message or something like that. // The Send dialog allows to specify a default ID, and that can be a group ID as well (although not officially documented, so might stop working at any point without prior notice) - but I have currently no possibility to try if that also works for users that are just members of the closed group, [...]

Comment: [...] and not admin. If so, you could let them share a link to the group feed and add a message (link is mandatory.) But be also aware that users can remove the default recipient you specify for the dialog, and/or add other recipients themselves - might want to consider carefully whether that might leak any sensitive data, depending on what links users will be sharing and what they might talk about in the messages they add.

Comment: *he Send dialog allows to specify a default ID, and that can be a group ID as well (although not officially documented, so might stop working at any point without prior notice) * I did not quite understand this part but I think that may be the solution, can you explain me in detail please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog